# How to add PO Receipt to Landed Cost via Web Service in Acumatica?

Tags: json, web-services, acumatica

I've been currently tasked to find a way to avoid human error when the Import department create Landed Costs, so I've decided to add a new module to an existing internal tool, it reads xmls files, creates a json and it is send to the corresponding web service. It works fine but it doesn't add the Purchase Receipt that I've selected. (Since LC tab adds the Receipt with a button, I'm getting the information consulting the Receipt and appending the lines to the json).

Here's the json I'm sending. LandedCostDetails is the part where I'm getting no results:

```
{
    "LinkDocumento": {
        "value": "document"
    },
    "Vendor": {
        "value": "0990015325001"
    },
    "VendorRef": {
        "value": "002001000240797"
    },
    "LCInfo": [
        {
            "Branch": {
                "value": "MAIN"
            },
            "LandedCostCode": {
                "value": "VALADVALOREM"
            },
            "Amount": {
                "value": 106.96
            }
        }
    ],
    "LandedCostDetails": [
        {
            "Branch":"MAIN",
            "DocType":"LC",
            "InventoryID": "NMCA364",
            "Warehouse": "GIT",
            "UOM": "UNIT",
            "ReceiptQty": 1.00,
            "Weight": 0.0,
            "Volume": 0.0,
            "ExtCost": 55000.00,
            "Currency": "USD",
            "AllocatedAmount": 0.0,
            "POReceiptNbr": "POR007893",
            "POReceiptLineNbr": 1,
            "LineNbr": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I check the created Landed Cost but there's no Receipt added.

The link with the parameters:

localhost/eoa/entity/EOSWS/20.200.001/LandedCost?$select=ReferenceNbr,Vendor,VendorRef,LinkDocumento,LCInfo,ReceiptsToApply&$expand=LCInfo,ReceiptsToApply

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the URL parameters you are using for this? Without a URL Parameter $expand=LandedCostDetails it will not add the detail.

Comment: I've edited the question to show the whole url

Comment: Can you also share the web service endpoint in a customization project, this is not a standard Acumatica endpoint. Also it seems like you are conflating a property called "receiptstoapply" with "LandedCostDetails", you might be using the object name in the $select and $expand instead of the property name